# R rules for new variable based on current previous and next value

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

data

```
data=data.frame("person"=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4),
                 "score"=c(1,2,1,3,4,3,1,2,1,3,1,2,3,1,3,2,2,3,1,3,3),
                  "want"=c(1,1,1,3,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,3,3))
```

I will do my best here to explain what I hope to achieve.

Basically I want to create the 'want' column which depends on the previous, current, and next values.

In the data, an individual can have a score of 1,2,3,4. I want a new variable 'want' that follows these rules:

1. a score of 3 will be assigned at time T if there was a score of 3 at time T-1 and a score of 2 or 3 at time T+1.
2. a score of 3 will be assigned at time T if there was a score of 3 at time T and a score of 4 at time T+1.
3. otherwise, all score values should be a 1 EXCEPT if there is a 4.

Comment: how do you plan to handle the first row, for which is impossible to estimate the T-1 score? In the same vein, how do you plan to handle the last row, for which there's no T+1 observation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it suppoused to look like your `want` column? This gives different results, but appears to be following your logic:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  mutate(want2 = case_when(
    (lag(score) == 3 & lead(score) %in% c(2,3)) ~ 3,
    score == 3 & lead(score) == 4 ~ 3,
    T ~ 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your want columns is not following your own rules. Please notice that you have a 4 in the 5th position, but there's no rule to assign a 4 (other values seem to be miscalculated, as per your rules).

```
# load packages
library(data.table)

# create data
dt <- data.table(person = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4),
                 score = c(1,2,1,3,4,3,1,2,1,3,1,2,3,1,3,2,2,3,1,3,3))

# Make lead and lag vectors
dt[, tMinus := shift(score, 1, type = "lag")]
dt[, tPlus := shift(score, 1, type = "lead")]

# calculate want
dt[, want := 1][tMinus == 3 & tPlus %in% 2:3, want := 3][score == 3 & tPlus == 4, want := 3]

# remove unneeded columns
dt[, c("tMinus", "tPlus") := NULL]
```

This produces the result:

```
> dt
    person score want
 1:      1     1    1
 2:      1     2    1
 3:      1     1    1
 4:      1     3    3
 5:      1     4    3
 6:      2     3    1
 7:      2     1    3
 8:      2     2    1
 9:      2     1    1
10:      2     3    1
11:      2     1    3
12:      3     2    1
13:      3     3    1
14:      3     1    3
15:      3     3    1
16:      3     2    3
17:      4     2    1
18:      4     3    1
19:      4     1    3
20:      4     3    1
21:      4     3    1
    person score want
```

It wasn't clear if you wanted to calculate the `want` by `person`. If so, then consider the next code:

```
dt[, tPlus := shift(score, 1, type = "lead"), by = person]
dt[, tMinus := shift(score, 1, type = "lag"), by = person]
dt[, want := 1][tMinus == 3 & tPlus %in% 2:3, 
                want := 3][score == 3 & tPlus == 4, 
                           want := 3][, 
          c("tMinus", "tPlus") := NULL][]
```